# word-wrap in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I really want to know why and how to fix this thing.

[image]

The first image is from IE8 while the second is from Chrome.
What I want is the second one. Any advice?

Comment: Please share your CSS and put together a jsFiddle.

Comment: I can't use chrome.
And this is just simple table with width: auto tds. It's just that IE renders it differently.

I'll try to put up a fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to use the css rule:

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

This prevents text from going onto the next line

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely to do with font rendering. It's different between browsers and some will render ever so slightly larger that others. Ultimately you don't want to be trying to fit words into spaces exact to the pixel. If you want to do that make sure you're using fluid layouts with percentage width and auto height.